# Is it possible to select a set of instance from a data set by inputting one instance?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-mining, data-science

I have a data set which has many features. Now I want to select a set of instance based on an input of a new instance. Actually, I want to find a percentage from the selective set of instance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. If the community is to help you effectively, we need a bit more information. Please edit your question to include your source code as far as you gave got it, and an example of the output you want. Thanks.

Comment: for 'gave' read 'have', sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to *search* similar objects?

That is called "similarity search", not machine learning, data science, etc. - if you Google, you will find various books, tutorials, libraries, etc.